# Why is some_func(…) != some_func.call(this, …) in a constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

I always assumed that `some_function(...)` was exactly the same as `some_function.call(this, ...)`. This seems not to hold true for calls in constructors / an object construction context:

```js
function Class(members, parent) {
    function Ctor(value) {
        members.__init__.call(this, value);
        return this;
    };
    Ctor.prototype = members;
    Ctor.prototype.__proto__ = parent.prototype;
    return Ctor;
}

var Base = Class({
    __init__: function(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}, {});

var Child = Class({
    __init__: function(value) {
        // Base(value*2); ← WON'T WORK AS EXPECTED
        Base.call(this, value*2); // works just fine
    }
}, Base);
```

In `Child.__init__` it in necessary to use the explicit call to `Base.call(this, value)`. If I don't use this lengthy expressing, `this` would name the global object (`window` in browsers) in the called base constructor. With `"use strict"` an error would be thrown as there is no global object in strict mode.

Can someone please explain why I have to use `Func.call(this, ...)` in this example?

(Tested with Node.js v0.6.12 and Opera 12.50.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling a function with `.call` is different from just invoking it with `()`. With `.call` you explicitly set the value of `this` for the call in the first argument. With normal invocation, the `this` value will implicitly be the global object or `undefined`, depending on whether strict mode is enabled or not.

```
func.call({}, 1); //Call the function func with `this` set to the object and pass 1 as the first argument

func(1); //Call the function func with 1 as the first argument. The value of this inside the function depends on whether strict mode is on or off.
```

See [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

---

> I always assumed that some_function(...) was exactly the same as
>   some_function.call(this, ...). This seems not to hold true for calls
>   in constructors / an object construction context:

That's not true, they are never the same. You are probably confusing it with calling a function as a property of some object. `obj.method()` will mean that `obj` is the value of `this` for the method call and it would be effectively the same as `obj.method.call(obj)`.